# how to define generic type based on passed arguments which is a union type

Tags: typescript

I have following similar types:

```js
class ActionFoo {
  action: 'foo';
  foo: string;
}
class ActionBar {
  action: 'bar';
  bar: number;
}
```

and some handler functions for each kind of defined "action", e.g.

```js
function fooHandler(action: ActionFoo) {
  // do something
}
function barHandler(action: ActionBar) {
  // do something
}
```

The question is to create a util function to handling all these cases. I tried following, but the predicted types was wrong for handlers.

```js
type ActionHandler<T extends { action: string }, O = any> = (action: T) => O; // type define for handler

function handleAction<T extends { action: string }, O = any>(
  action: T,
  handlers: {[key in T['action']]: ActionHandler<T, O>}
) {
  const handler = handlers[action.action];
  if (handler) return handler(action);
  throw new Error('not implemented');
}

type Action = ActionFoo | ActionBar;

function run(action: Action) {
  return handleAction(action, {
    foo: action => fooHandler(action), // ts compiler complaint type error (TS2345) for `action` for missing `foo` field
    bar: action => barHandler(action), // similar error
  });
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] without any missing types or values, and where the only problems with the code are the ones you're asking about, when others run it in an IDE under `--strict` (or presumably under a different set of compiler options, but then you'd need to specify those).  Right now I see errors you're not asking about (class properties not initialized, error inside `handleAction`, and no `action` value in existence) and I don't see the error you are asking about.  Could you please fix address that so we can work on it?

Comment: @jcalz updated the last part. ts reports ts2345 on given type `ActionFoo | ActionBar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. To let ts reasoning correct type for union type `Action` in `ActionHandler`, it has to combine the key type with the value type.

```js
type ActionHandler<T extends { action: string }, O = any> = (action: T) => O; // type define for handler

function handleAction<T extends { action: string }, O = any>(
  action: T,
  handlers: { [K in T['action']]: ActionHandler<T & { action: K }, O> } // <--- added & { action: K } to combine value type with key type
) {
  const handler = handlers[action.action];
  if (handler) return handler(action);
  throw new Error('not implemented');
}
```